# Servers can only ping to domain controllers and not to each other

Tags: ping

I have made my own test environment and I am having problems with pinging other servers from one server. All servers can ping to domain controllers and they get responded back. When I ping from a server to another server, I get following message "Destination host unreachable." Running Windows Server 2012 R2 all on servers and DCs

They all have static IPs

Comment: check if the windows firewall disabled (for testing) or allow ICMP Protocol.

Comment: Do you have this on a different network with a firewall between?

Comment: "destination host unreachable" sounds more like a routing problem than a firewall problem.

Comment: DIsable firewalls and try again. If that doesn't help can you provide some `ipconfig /all` output for two systems that can't ping each other?

Comment: Disabling firewall worked. thanks for the help guys.

Comment: What `real` problem have you solved?

Answer (score -1):

Check to make sure all systems are listed properly in DNS. For your DC follow this, or check your install against it.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12370.windows-server-2012-set-up-your-first-domain-controller-step-by-step.aspx

We typically assume that if you don't mention the version of OS your using the most current, if not don't forget to mention the version (2005/2008/2012) you'll get more specific answers that way.

ALSO check your hosts files:
C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
The best way to find this is windows explorer and type the path, the etc folder is typically hidden.

Answer (score -1):

*I infer you're referring to ICMP (IPv4) echo-request, not to its ICMPv6 analogon.*

It appears your servers are connected by a node that acts as a gateway in the sense of [rfc792](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc792):

> Destination Unreachable Message
>
> ```
>      [...]
>     Code
>       [...]
>       1 = host unreachable;
>
>   [...]
>
>   Codes 0, 1, 4, and 5 may be received from a gateway.  Codes 2 and
>   3 may be received from a host.
> ```

that cannot (or doesn't) forward the ICMP echo-request.

More in-depth analysis of the issue would require more in-depth information about your network topology.